# Assigning data from SAS data set to variable (SAS E Guide 5.1)

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I use SAS to execute queries, and sometimes send an email to my team afterward to confirm that the query has executed. However, I never really know if it was successful unless I check manually.

For example, I have a SAS job that executes a stored procedure which appends a table with more data from today. I want to be able to add the MAX(date) from that table to email text, or a COUNT(*) where the date is today to the email, so I can know how many records were added.

Here is what I would imagine it would look like:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE sasData AS
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS myRecordCount
    FROM
        tableName
;QUIT;

%LET newVariable = sasData.myRecordCount;
```

So, I know the above isn't how it works, but it's the idea.

Can anyone show me how to do this properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below to directly store the result in the macro variable:

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
    SELECT
        count(*) INTO:myRecordCount
    FROM tableName;
QUIT;
```

As an aside, you can also store a list of values into a macro variable by using SEPARATED BY to specify a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL you can get count of observations processed by the previous SQL statement in the automatic macro variable SQLOBS.  Save it to another macro variable as it will be overwritten when the next SQL statement runs.

```
proc sql ;
  create table class as select * from sashelp.class ;
%let nobs=&sqlobs ;
  insert into class select * from sashelp.class where name like 'A%' ;
%let nobs2=&sqlobs ;

%put &=nobs &=nobs2 ;
NOBS=19 NOBS2=2
```

You can use the INTO clause to create macro variables.

```
select count(*)
     , max(age)
into :nobs3 trimmed 
   , :max_age trimmed
from sashelp.class 
;
```